# Bullet wont collide for the other player

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, instantiation, collision, photon

I've been working on a flamethrower as one of my weapons. Its a platform multiplayer online game. It is also working with photon. I am having a problem with the flames (and the other rifles bullets too).

The flames which the flamethrower shoots are being instantiated with PhotonNetwork.Instantiate. And they do collide with the player which instantiated them, and the other player is able to see them instantiated and their movement. But for some reason the player which instantiates them sees who they collide to and sees them collided but the other player which is shot at won't see the flames collided with himself or with the walls. The flames own their script of collision and movement and a photonView component.

What do I do to solve this issue?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED - Had to put a rigidbody on the bullet. :)